# find and replace parameter value within an array in div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div where I want to replace a value of a parameter within an array.

My php code to generate the html is the following

```
<div id="data1<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" data-url="<?php echo 'post/comment', 
      array('post_id' => $data['id'], 'comment_id' => $data['c_id'])); ?>"></div>
```

when page is rendered data-url contains

```
/blog/index.php/post/updateComment?post_id=16&comment_id=''
```

I want to put a value in `comment_id`, something like `comment_id=12`

I tried first to see if I can get the data-url value

but when I do

```
$('#data1).map(function(){

          alert(this.data-url);
});
```

it returns  NaN

```
$('#data1).map(function(){

          alert(this.id);
});
```

return the id  as expected

I'd like to know if there is way to search & replace  `comment_id=''`  by `comment_id=12`

Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this:

```
alert($(this).attr('data-url'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.map()` in this context since you have selected an `id`,

Try,

```
$('#data1').data('url');
```

Please read here to know more about [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) here.